# signature next_permutation c++

Tags: c++, std, permutation

I was wondering whether there is a simple way of knowing the [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation) (signature) of permutations created by c++'s `std::next_permutation` from the order in which they are created.

```
int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    std::vector<int> mask {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    do 
    {
        counter++;
        // then determine the parity of permutation from knowledge of the counter
    } while (std::next_permutation(mask.begin(), mask.end()));
}
```

or alternatively, is there a built in function to determine the parity of a permutation?

Comment: what do you mean by "parity (signature) of permutation"? Can you give an example?

Comment: @bolov: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT : The rule below is wrong. I'm trying to fix it.**

It seems that there is a nice combinatorial miracle here ! If you enumerate the permutation in lexicographic order (as it is specified by C++ standard, see e.g: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation), then some experiment seems to indicate that the sign follows the following rules:
start with one, then change sign, then change sign every other permutation.

```
[1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1 ...]
```

I don't currently understand why, but I checked that this this is true upto size ***. Here is n=4 for example:

```
 ([1, 2, 3, 4], 1)
 ([1, 2, 4, 3], -1)
 ([1, 3, 2, 4], -1)
 ([1, 3, 4, 2], 1)
 ([1, 4, 2, 3], 1)
 ([1, 4, 3, 2], -1)
 ([2, 1, 3, 4], -1)
 ([2, 1, 4, 3], 1)
 ([2, 3, 1, 4], 1)
 ([2, 3, 4, 1], -1)
 ([2, 4, 1, 3], -1)
 ([2, 4, 3, 1], 1)
 ([3, 1, 2, 4], 1)
 ([3, 1, 4, 2], -1)
 ([3, 2, 1, 4], -1)
 ([3, 2, 4, 1], 1)
 ([3, 4, 1, 2], 1)
 ([3, 4, 2, 1], -1)
 ([4, 1, 2, 3], -1)
 ([4, 1, 3, 2], 1)
 ([4, 2, 1, 3], 1)
 ([4, 2, 3, 1], -1)
 ([4, 3, 1, 2], -1)
 ([4, 3, 2, 1], 1)
```

I think this answers you question. I'll get back here as soon I'll find an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is an existing function like that, but you can implement your own `next_permutation` with instrumentation. Something like:

```
enum class Parity {Even, Odd};

Parity operator+ (Parity parity, std::size_t count)
{
    return static_cast<Parity>((static_cast<std::size_t>(parity) + count) % 2);
}

template<typename It>
bool next_permutation(It begin, It end, Parity& parity)
{
    if (begin == end)
        return false;

    It i = begin;
    ++i;
    if (i == end)
        return false;

    i = end;
    --i;

    while (true)
    {
        It j = i;
        --i;

        if (*i < *j)
        {
            It k = end;

            while (!(*i < *--k))
                /* pass */;

            std::iter_swap(i, k);
            parity = parity + 1;
            std::reverse(j, end);
            parity = parity + std::distance(j, end) / 2;
            return true;
        }

        if (i == begin)
        {
            std::reverse(begin, end);
            parity = parity + std::distance(begin, end) / 2;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/I3fjgt)